# RxJavaPlugins, the pattern behind

Tags: java, rx-java2, reactive

I want to reproduce the "static" injection of RxJava using the RxJavaPlugins and i'am wondring if the design of this class is a well known pattern !?

I have a basic model class for all my events

```java
import lombok.Getter;

public abstract class BasicEvent {

    @Getter
    private final String id;

    @Getter
    private final long timestamp;

    public BasicEvent() {
        this.id = IDGenerator.BY_COUNTER.generate();
        this.timestamp = TimePlayer.clock().timestamp();
    }
}
```

The main drawback of the class above is the testability. I cannot change the IDGenerator and the TimePlayer.

I think that having a third party class, designed like RxJavaPlugins could help me changing my metadata generators for tests

**UPDATE** .

I've followed the RxJavaPlugins solution for keeping model's creation simple, without worrying about the id and the timestamp (i called the two fields metadata), here is solution a found.

```
public BasicEvent() {
    this.id = MetaGenerator.idGenerator().generate();
    this.timestamp = MetaGenerator.timePlayer().timestamp();
}


public class MetaGenerator {

    public static IDGenerator idGenerator() {
        // DGenerator.BY_COUNTER is the default value
        return MetaGeneratorPlugins.onIDGenerator(IDGenerator.BY_COUNTER);
    }

    public static TimePlayer timePlayer() {
        return MetaGeneratorPlugins.onTimePlayer(TimePlayer.realtime);
    }
}

public class MetaGeneratorPlugins {

    private static Function<? super TimePlayer, ? extends TimePlayer> onTimePlayerHandler;
    private static Function<? super IDGenerator, ? extends IDGenerator> onIDGeneratorHandler;

    public static void setTimePlayerHandler(@Nullable Function<? super TimePlayer, ? extends TimePlayer> handler) {
        onTimePlayerHandler = handler;
    }

    public static void setIDGeneratorHandler(@Nullable Function<? super IDGenerator, ? extends IDGenerator> handler) {
        onIDGeneratorHandler = handler;
    }

    //return the default value or the value returned by the handler
    public static TimePlayer onTimePlayer(@Nonnull TimePlayer defaultScheduler) {
        if (onTimePlayerHandler == null) {
            return defaultScheduler;
        }
        return apply(onTimePlayerHandler, defaultScheduler);
    }

    public static IDGenerator onIDGenerator(@Nonnull IDGenerator defaultScheduler) {
        if (onIDGeneratorHandler == null) {
            return defaultScheduler;
        }
        return apply(onIDGeneratorHandler, defaultScheduler);
    }

    private static <T, R> R apply(@Nonnull Function<T, R> f, @Nonnull T t) {
        return f.apply(t);
    }
}
```

In my tests now i can change this MetaGenerator's implementation by calling MetaGeneratorPlugins

```
MetaGeneratorPlugins.setIDGeneratorHandler(IDGenerator.INCREMENTAL);
MetaGeneratorPlugins.setTimePlayerHandler(TimePlayer.simulated);
```

This is how RxJavaPlugins works, i have been inspired by they solution,

Now the creation of my models are simple and it works for production and tests.

Answer (score 2):

Change the design of `BasicEvent` so that the `id` and `timestamp` are bound in a more testable fashion.

Introduce a "stamper" interface:

```
public interface Stamper {
  String generateId();
  long   generateTimestamp();
}
```

The "default" implementation would look like:

```
public RealTimeStamper implements Stamper {
  @Override public String generateId() {
    return IDGenerator.BY_COUNTER.generate();
  }
  @Override public long generateTimestamp() {
    return TimePlayer.clock().timestamp();
  }
}
```

Provide a testable implementation of `Stamper`. Then bind the appropriate implementation using whatever dependency injection process you use.

```
public abstract class BasicEvent {
  static Stamper stamper;
  ...
  public BasicEvent() {
    this.id = stamper.generateId();
    this.timestamp = stamper.generateTimestamp();
  }
}
```

The `stamper` field can be injected either manually or using a dependency injection framework.

Comment: Sorry i can't show you my final code because of the auto ban, i'll try to put it on github for more explanation

Comment: i've updated my poste above. My response is after the **UPDATE** line

Comment: Your solution looks to be a comprehensive answer to your original question. It uses dependency injection to provide the values that you need when you need them. As such, there is nothing I can add to it. Or remove.

Comment: your solution works too, but what i dislike is the stamper field, which breaks the single responsability (separation of concerns) and the encapsulation principals

Comment: In a context where both the `id` and the `timestamp` have to be applied together, `Stamper` is carrying out a single responsibility. In other contexts, where `id` and `timestamp` have no relationship to each other, they should be de-coupled.